# How to upload huge files in DataBase?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Uploading file from Computer to Database(server)
            String filename = "", filetype = "", filesize = "";
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                UploadLogic bl=new UploadLogic();
                filename = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
                filesize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength.ToString();
                filetype = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
                byte[] filepath = new byte[FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength];
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(filepath, 0, FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength);
                int i = bl.upload_file(filename, filesize, filetype, filepath);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds = bl.uploaded_Content();
                ListBox1.DataSource = ds;
                ListBox1.DataTextField = "File_Name";
                ListBox1.DataValueField = "File_Name";
                //Bind your Data
                ListBox1.DataBind();
            }

        }
```

This code uploads only file which is less than 1MB. If i want to upload huge files its not happening. Can any one tell me Why?

Comment: dont uplaod files to DB. save their location instead !

Comment: Choking the database with huge files is an excellent way to kill the system in no time

Comment: Normally, you'd write large files via a loop over a small buffer. You should not be trying to load that into a `byte[]`. Not really worth adding an example of this, though, because like all the other comments say: this is not a great idea *in the first case*.

Comment: it's probably resulting in a statement larger than the allowable SQL statement size - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Comment: @joocer we can't see the actual command, but I would **expect** that data to be a parameter value, not part of the statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [httpRuntime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

You need to edit your `web.config`

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="SIZE" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

By default it will be set to `4096kb`

Anyway, if the file size is reasonably high it will be be a good solution to upload the file into database.

Comment: The Size parameter is expresed in KB. For example, if you want 8MB max, set it to 8192

Comment: By default its 4096kb? means 4MB.. Right??

Comment: Then if i load 2MB file its throwing an error.. like Operation timeout

Comment: @SyedYunus: Are you sure that happens when you uploading smaller files?? Anyway, have a look at this article **http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx**

Answer (score 1):

Edit your web.config

```
<httpRuntime useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true|false"
             maxRequestLength="size in kbytes"
             executionTimeout="seconds"
             minFreeThreads="number of threads"
             minFreeLocalRequestFreeThreads="number of threads"
             appRequestQueueLimit="number of requests"
             versionHeader="version string"/>
```

Source  [Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)